# htaccess URL overwrite - Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I have some URLs that I would need to overwrite so that if someone looks at the source code they can't actually see the real URLs for the product images in Magento. Currently, the link is as

```
externalsub.domain.com/images/image123.jpg
```

I want to make it as

```
mydomain.com/images/image123.jpg
```

How can I achieve this via .htaccess? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have mod_proxy loaded in your apache server?

Comment: I do have mod_proxy on apache.

Answer (score 1):

Then in an htaccess file, you can use this (above whatever rules you may already have):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$ http://externalsub.domain.com/images/$1 [L,P]
```

You don't need the line turning on the rewrite engine if you already have that (only needs to be in your file once).

Comment: Sorry had an urgent situation, couldn't test before now. This doesn't change anything. The old URL still stays as is. any ideas?